# how to rename a family/pattern of branches in one step

Tags: git

I know that I can rename a branch with

```
git branch -m new-branch-name
```

And also that I can rename that branch from another branch with:

```
git branch -m old-branch-name new-branch-name
```

but I want to know if i can rename a range of branches replacing a path from all of them. For example

```
foo/bar/1.2
foo/baracca/1.2
foo/baratro/1.2
foo/barbabietola/1.2
foo/bartender/1.2
```

Should be changed in "replace 1.2 in 1.3"

```
foo/bar/1.3
foo/baracca/1.3
foo/baratro/1.3
foo/barbabietola/1.3
foo/bartender/1.3
```

or "replace foo with me"

```
meh/bar/1.2
meh/baracca/1.2
meh/baratro/1.2
meh/barbabietola/1.2
meh/bartender/1.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
git branch | grep 1.2 | while read branch; do
    new_branch=$( echo $branch | sed 's/1.2/1.3/' )
    echo moving $branch to $new_branch

    # enable next line when we are sure the name of the branches is correct
    # git branch -m $branch $new_branch
done
```

Comment: I was trying to do same thing with one single line

Comment: a 1-liner is the same thing adding ; for each line: ```git branch | grep 1.2 | while read branch; do new_branch=$( echo $branch | sed 's/1.2/1.3/' ); echo moving $branch to $new_branch; git branch -m $branch $new_branch; done```